# Installed app in Django not found when running tests

Tags: python, django, testing, module

I have a pretty simple Django app, that I am trying to run unit tests on. In my `tests.py` file I am trying to import the parent apps views file. I tried `from . import views` but got an error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I read that when a relative path does not work, you can try using an absolute path so I tried `from menu import views` but than got another error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'menu'
```

When I run a local server for the application it works just fine. Its only when I run `coverage run 'coverage run menu/tests.py`. Since it is running fine, and the module is in my `settings` installed apps, I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

menu/tests.py

```
import unittest

from menu import views

class ModelTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_menu(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu',
    'django_nose'
)
```

Traceback

```
timothybaney$ coverage run menu/tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "menu/tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from menu import views
ImportError: No module named 'menu'
```

Comment: did you tried to rename it, i.e. 'mymenu'?

Comment: Yeah just tried it, and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: can you show more log?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only thing I get from the Traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not much information you gave us.. but when I take a look at the Traceback it says `File 'menu/tests.py'`. So if the views.py is also inside the menu Folder you just can write:

```
import views
```

If the views.py is in the main folder you could write:

```
from ..main import views   #replace 'main' with your folder name
```

Comment: Thanks Don, oddly enough this worked. I feel like thats just as relative as from . import views, but I'll have to look around more to see why this happened in the first place.